# Reload CollectionView data on Button Pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a camera app that displays thumbnails of the user's photo library in a **UICollectionView** layered on top of the live camera feed UIView.

I was hoping that I could easily 'refresh' the contents of the UICollectionView every time the user takes a new photo using the `reloadData()` property:

```
@IBAction func snapNewPhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    takePhotoMethod()
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

and this is my takePhoto method:

```
func takePhotoMethod () {
    if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            buffer, error in

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer!)
            self.imageArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)

            print ("Photo taken", self.imageArray.count)
        })
    }
}
```

This does not work, I guess the solution is a bit more complex, do I have to 'reload' the entire **View Controller** to reload the **UICollectionView** or is there another more eloquent approach?

Comment: This is a bit heavy-handed, but should work.  What problems are you seeing?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the __takePhotoMethod__?

Comment: `reloadData’ just gets the collectionview to redraw all of the cells by calling its data source methods. Have you updated the data that these data source methods are accessing?  Ie. if you have loaded the photo library into an array for the data source methods, have you refreshed that array?  Also, since you are only adding one new photo it would be visually cleaner to just add that one new photo to the data source array and call insert the new cell into the collection rather than reload the entire thing

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes that sounds like the way to go thanks. I will try to post the answer here when I crack it.

Comment: @Adeel, I added the method I use to take photos

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia the Collectionview UI does not update

Comment: it happens because of threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
func takePhotoMethod () {
if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
    sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
        buffer, error in

        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer!)
        self.imageArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)
        myCollectionView.reloadData()//reload must be done in here.
        print ("Photo taken", self.imageArray.count)
    })
}
```

}